# How to export RYU Stats

Tags: python, ryu

With RYU controller, how can I export all stats (throughout the monitoring time) into csv file as time series stats using e.g., [simple_monitor](https://github.com/faucetsdn/ryu/blob/master/ryu/app/simple_monitor_13.py) application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to export the stats by creating a new file in the `_port_stats_reply_handler` function:

```
file = open('stats.csv', 'a')
```

Then in the loop I added:

```
for stat in sorted(body, key=attrgetter('port_no')):
            file.write("\n{},{},{},{},{},{}"
            .format(ev.msg.datapath.id,
            stat.port_no, stat.rx_packets, stat.rx_dropped,
            stat.tx_packets, stat.tx_dropped))
```